# Count the number of possible "non-identical" triangles

Tags: arrays, c

What I am considering as identical here is for example a
triangle with sides such as: 3-4-5 and a triangle 5-3-4.
I have to count the number of possible triangles with the exception of the identical ones.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-number-of-triangles-possible/ - my code is basically the brute force method. I've tried using for to remove all identical triangles from the possible triangles, but it takes too long with a bigger array.

I'd like to figure out how to do it more efficiently, is it possible to modify the input array so that these identical triangles don't even form to begin with?

Comment: I am confused by your question. Doesn't the geeksforgeeks page you listed have an efficient algorithm which you can use?

Comment: It has an algorithm for all possible triangles, im trying to find the count of all possible triangles that are not identical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get identical triangles unless there are duplicates in the data set.

One suggestion: you only need to check that the two short sides sum to greater than the long side.  So, if you sort your array before starting the loops, you only have to check one combination instead of 3.

Once they are sorted, you can shortcut the duplicate check by comparing this entry to the previous entry at this level.  So, `if( arr[j] == arr[j-1] ) continue;` and `if( arr[k] == arr[k-1] ) continue;`.  You know that j-1 and k-1 are valid indices because neither loop starts at 0.

Comment: thanks that helped ,but i also had to check if j and k weren't j+1 and k+1 (because j-1 would on the first loop be equal to i so it would skip the first loop, the same for k). I also had a duplicate check loop i.